# Android NDK thrid party static library - ndk build giving error : jni/libAT_int.a:1:1: invalid character

Tags: android-ndk, static-libraries

I'm trying to integrate static library libAT_int.a
I have successfully integrated it in iOS app.

**lipo -info libAT_int.a 
Architectures in the fat file: libAT_int.a are: armv6 armv7**

But when i'm integrating it with Android NDK. I'm getting error during ndk build
**error: jni/libAT_int.a:1:1: invalid character**

**Android.mk  has following content :**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := AT  
ifeq ($(APP_ABI), armeabi-v7a)
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libAT_int.a  
else
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libAT_int.a  
endif
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += rtti exceptions
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp .h


include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)  

include $(CLEAR_VARS)   

LOCAL_MODULE    := MusicSDK
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := MusicSDK.cpp

LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += rtti exceptions
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp .h

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := AT  


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a static library built for iOS when building for Android, you need a static library built specifically for Android.